# Regarding the shopping questions!

Tags: discussion

Are shopping question where a user(Me) has done a bit of research but is noob and doesn't want to stupidly spend money on a High end(> 150$) electronic measurement device and is comparing two products but cannot figure out which one suits his needs valid?

Comment: I bet some people here chuckles a bit when you call $150 "high end". You _might_ find a high end passive oscilloscope probe for that amount. :) But everything is relative...

Comment: You'll get better results in [our EE.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering) with those questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comparing two products would be off-topic, but a more general discussion about how to measure what you need would be fine.

Comment: Ok. Not even comparing two products specifications for the needs of hobby electronics use?

Comment: Right. That would be too specific to your particular needs. If it's for"general hobbyist use", that would be too speculative.

Comment: Alright. Thanks :)

Comment: If you have a highly specific question about the *meaning* of a particular parameter (and one not readily determined from the data sheet or a web search) that could potentially be on topic, but a question of this sort is going to start out with a very large amount of suspicion against it, so that you would have to very clearly state a *technical* query rather be seeking a preference or anticipated usefulness *opinion*.